# I'am unable to read characters using read function in python3 files

Tags: python-3.x

```
#First i created a file named tt.txt using following code:
f=open("tt.txt","w+")

print(f)
f.write("Hello")
f.write("World")
f.close()

#and now i want to read 3rd character so i wrote the following code: 
f=open("tt.txt","r")
text=f.read()
print(text)
print(f.read(2))
#But it dosen't work
```

I cannot access the third element i.e 'l' using read(). I don't whether i could use 2 as a parameter

Comment: `text=f.read()` will move the file pointer to the end of file. After that `print(f.read(2))` will have nothing to read. Use `f.seek(0)` to reset file pointer!

Comment: I deleted the "text=f.read()" line.When I run the code i got the output as "He"

Comment: If you want to read only the third character use `f.read()[3]`

Comment: Thanks , it works. Does the same code works for python 2.7 ??

Comment: Yes it will work on python 2.7 as well!